# Why i don't get the maximum recursion number in python?

Tags: python

```
try:
    start = 0
    def recursion():
        global start
        def repeat():
            global start

            print('hello world')
            start += 1
            print(recursion())
            
        print(repeat())

    print(recursion())
    
except RecursionError:
    print('you eached the limit')
    print(' ')
    print('recursion :',start, 'times')
```

result :

```
hello world
hello world
you eached the limit

recursion : 497 times
```

Why i don't get the maximum number of recursion in python or is this the maximum number ?

Comment: Looks like your recursion limit is set to 1000. Because you're using 2 functions, it stops at 500. It actually cuts out 3 short because of the print. You can change it by doing `import sys; sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)`.

Comment: @TheThonnu You're missing the fact OP is ping-ponging between two functions, `repeat()` and `recursion()`.

Comment: @AKX - yeah, thanks, I didn't see that. I thought it had a default of 1000, so that looked a bit strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default recursion limit is 1000.

```
>>> sys.getrecursionlimit()
1000
```

A program with a single recursive function will reach `999`:

```
start = 0

try:
    def recursion():
        global start
        start += 1
        recursion()
    recursion()
except RecursionError:
    print('recursion :', start, 'times')
```

prints out

```
recursion : 999 times
```

Your program is creating a stack that has `recursion()`, then `repeat()`, then `recursion()`, etc., and a `print()` call, so it makes sense you reach a bit under half of that.

Comment: Run *this* program and get - ```recursion : 1025 times```.   Run OP's and get ```506``` times.

Comment: @DanielHao Depends on your interpreter, I suppose.

Comment: Just to confirm - the *theroy* is  ```Spot on```. ...  ;-)